# Mongoose: Update parent on child update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to update all associated nested parents on child update? I'm creating a multi-level navbar. The first nested items display without any issues. However, all items 2+ levels deep don't update. I believe this is the problem:

```
A
|
|_B
  |
  |_C
```

A knows that B exists. B knows that C exists. But A doesn't know that C exists.

This is the schema:

```
const DocumentSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, },
  subdocument: [this],
});
```

This is the returned data in mongodb:

A:

```
{
name: 'A'
_id:613bd8b351b6f2ba33d229e8
subdocument: 
    {
     name: 'B'
     _id: 613bd8b651b6f2ba33d229ef
     subdocument: {[]}
    }
}
```

B:

```
{
name: 'B'
_id: 613bd8b651b6f2ba33d229ef
subdocument: 
    {
     name: 'C'
     _id: 613bd8bc51b6f2ba33d229f5
     subdocument: {[]}
    }
}
```

C:

```
{
name: 'C'
_id: 613bd8bc51b6f2ba33d229f5
subdocument: {[]}
}
```

I'm trying to accomplish this (but for an unknown depth):

A:

```
{
name: 'A'
_id:613bd8b351b6f2ba33d229e8
subdocument: 
    {
     name: 'B'
     _id: 613bd8b651b6f2ba33d229ef
     subdocument: {
                  name: 'C'
                  _id: 613bd8bc51b6f2ba33d229f5
                  subdocument: {[]}
                  }
    }
}
```

How would I go about updating mongoDB so that the parent and all the children are updated to reflect the correct information? Thank you so much!

Comment: Would  `$graphLookup` help?

Comment: i think you cant because mongodb doesn't have functions, at least with 1 query that doesn't do any extra work, with more queries and setting a max level to search per query, maybe ,also what you want to update?which field and in how many subdocuments?

Comment: @Takis_ - Thank you both for the reply! I'm looking to update the subdocument field for all ID associated parents whenever a child or multi-level child is added. Put another way, when 'C' is added I'd like 'A' to know that 'B' now has a subdocument child element. Currently, when 'C' is added, 'A' still thinks that 'B' has no children. Does that make sense? I can explain it another way if not. I may also just need to rethink my nesting approach.